# Performing A GraphQL Selection On A Union for shopify SellingPlanPricingPolicy

Tags: graphql, shopify

I am trying to get union data using the Graphql APIfor Shopify and am unable to find any documentation on selecting data in unions.

Here is my current query:

```
query subscriptionPlans {
  sellingPlanGroup(id: 1234) {
    id
    name
    sellingPlans(first: 1) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          billingPolicy {
            ... on SellingPlanRecurringBillingPolicy {
              interval
              intervalCount
            }
          }
          pricingPolicies {
            on
            SellingPlanRecurringPricingPolicy {
              afterCycle
              adjustmentType
              adjustmentValue {
                on
                SellingPlanPricingPolicyPercentageValue {
                  percentage
                }
                on
                MoneyV2 {
                  amount
                  currencyCode
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to retrieve the sellingPlans in this scenario. When I get to the SellingPlanPricingPolicy portion I run into issues. I am receiving the error:

```
Selections can't be made directly on unions (see selections on SellingPlanPricingPolicy)
```

However, I am unable to find any documentation on making selections using the documentation at: https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/products-and-collections/sellingplanpricingpoli...

Any help with this would be appreciated. I just need an example of how to select this information.

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer in https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#meta-fields. In case of sponsorEntity it looks like this:

```
      sponsorEntity {
        ... on User {
          name
        }
      }
```

The solution is to select the attributes on the respective sub-type of the union.